# How to check if object is referenced before deleting? (Many To Many Relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am quite new in the **ruby on rails** world. I have two classes, A and B and defining in the following way:

```
class AClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :a_b_class
end

class ABClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :attr1, :attr2

  belongs_to :a_class
  belongs_to :b_class

  attr_accessible :attr1,:attr2,:a_class, b_class
end

class BClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :attr4, :attr5

  has_many :a_b_class

  attr_accessible :attr4,:attr5
end
```

I am using ***activeadmin*** to administrate the databases data, etc.
The problem is that ***activeadmin*** allows me to delete a BClass object that is referenced by a AClass (through ABClass relationship) object so when I enter to the http://example.com/a_class the view failed because the view try to access to attr1 of a **nil** element. How can I add validation to the **model** in order to avoid delete a referenced object?

**EDITED**: I corrected the relationship, is a **many to many**

Answer (score 1):

I think your association is wrong somewhere first rectifie that e.g article has many comments,so comment has article_id,and comment has `validates_presence_of :article_id` not article and if you delete article respective comment should be deleted there for you need 'dependent=>:destroy"

```
class Article <AR
 has_many :comments,:dependent=>:destroy
end

class Comment <AR
 belongs_to :article
 attr_accessible :article_id,....
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will solve the problem - but can you try adding a belongs_to attribute to BClass to mark that it belongs to AClass?

```
belongs_to :a_class
```

Alsoo, you can't do this:

```
validates_presence_of :b_class_id
```

since there could be many ids..